# Show specific submenu and mark specific item as active when front page or specific node type is opened

Tags: 8, navigation

My front page is basically a view that lists teasers of node type article. How can I show a specific submenu and mark one item in this submenu as active (+ its parent) when

1) the front page is opened or

2) any article is opened?

I know 2) can be done with the module "Context Active Trail" and "Context UI", but I want to do it without a module and I think the module can't do 1) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

So finally I used the [Menu Position Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_position), which works perfectly.